# SQL Server is terminating this session. c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: sql-server, errors, sqldump

I Got Error:

> A user request from the session with SPID 183 generated a fatal exception. SQL Server is terminating this session. Contact Product Support Services with the dump produced in the log directory.

When I manually run the stored procedure it works ok, this one time got this error. Any idea what can cause it and how to prevent it?

Can someone explain what should I look for in the Dump File?

```shell
Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit) Version 15.0.2080.9

SQL Dump Log: (Had to cut part of the last part of the Dump due to characters limitation)
. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:46:58.08 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 6689 pages in 1.556 seconds (33.580 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 04:47:10.65 Backup      Database backed up. Database: MaltaExperience, creation date(time): 2020/07/20(10:20:33), pages dumped: 755, first LSN: 314:106:1, last LSN: 314:109:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\MaltaExperience_20220526_0447.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:47:10.66 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 745 pages in 0.197 seconds (29.512 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 04:47:14.82 Backup      Database backed up. Database: OMNIS_DW, creation date(time): 2019/11/18(12:21:57), pages dumped: 21770, first LSN: 829:515:1, last LSN: 829:518:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\OMNIS_DW_20220526_0447.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:47:14.84 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 21617 pages in 1.457 seconds (115.906 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 04:47:23.26 Backup      Database backed up. Database: STL_DEVELOPERTOOLS, creation date(time): 2019/12/03(18:53:01), pages dumped: 714, first LSN: 59:3426:1, last LSN: 59:3429:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\STL_DEVELOPERTOOLS_20220526_0447.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:47:23.28 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 705 pages in 0.107 seconds (51.415 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 04:47:34.52 Backup      Database backed up. Database: W6_BMIT, creation date(time): 2020/07/28(11:59:10), pages dumped: 74251, first LSN: 27089:468:1, last LSN: 27089:471:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\W6_BMIT_20220526_0447.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:47:34.54 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 74025 pages in 8.780 seconds (65.867 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 04:56:37.18 Backup      Database backed up. Database: W6_FB_KC_BMIT, creation date(time): 2020/07/27(20:48:58), pages dumped: 6268300, first LSN: 707616:301:1, last LSN: 707616:304:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\W6_FB_KC_BMIT_20220526_0447.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 04:56:37.19 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 6268265 pages in 527.577 seconds (92.822 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 05:02:43.66 Backup      Database backed up. Database: hMailServer, creation date(time): 2021/04/14(11:58:22), pages dumped: 651, first LSN: 108:12495:1, last LSN: 108:12498:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\hMailServer_20220526_0402.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 05:02:43.71 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 641 pages in 0.204 seconds (24.516 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 05:02:46.28 Backup      Database backed up. Database: RT_ILLY, creation date(time): 2020/11/27(16:16:32), pages dumped: 955, first LSN: 47:12768:1, last LSN: 47:12771:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\RT_ILLY_20220526_0402.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 05:02:46.30 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 945 pages in 0.153 seconds (48.212 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 05:02:48.96 Backup      Database backed up. Database: W6_SO_DEMO, creation date(time): 2021/12/02(15:50:03), pages dumped: 723, first LSN: 46:3173:1, last LSN: 46:3176:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\W6_SO_DEMO_20220526_0402.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 05:02:48.98 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 713 pages in 0.133 seconds (41.834 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 05:02:51.45 Backup      Database backed up. Database: W6_SO_ILLY, creation date(time): 2021/12/02(15:51:04), pages dumped: 803, first LSN: 48:9130:1, last LSN: 48:9133:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'Z:\BACKUP\SQL_DAILY_BACKUP\W6_SO_ILLY_20220526_0402.bak'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2022-05-26 05:02:51.47 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 793 pages in 0.128 seconds (48.351 MB/sec).
2022-05-26 06:30:01.21 spid183     CImageHelper::Init () Version-specific dbghelp.dll is not used
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     ***Stack Dump being sent to F:\SQL\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump2803.txt
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 183 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * *******************************************************************************
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *   05/26/22 06:30:01 spid 183
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *   Exception Address = 00007FFC96483D83 Module(sqllang+0000000000903D83)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *   Access Violation occurred reading address 000001EAC188A000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * Input Buffer 218 bytes -
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *             exec [spr_X_BOB_ExportAndEmail_v4] 32, 32026    exec [spr_X_S
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *  UMMARY_ExportAndEmail_v2] 32, 32026  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     *  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sqlservr                       00007FF789CF0000  00007FF789D8DFFF  0009e000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * ntdll                          00007FFCAC280000  00007FFCAC46CFFF  001ed000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * KERNEL32                       00007FFCAB950000  00007FFCABA03FFF  000b4000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * KERNELBASE                     00007FFCA8950000  00007FFCA8BE3FFF  00294000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * apphelp                        00007FFCA6480000  00007FFCA650BFFF  0008c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * CRYPT32                        00007FFCA86A0000  00007FFCA8894FFF  001f5000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * ucrtbase                       00007FFCA8310000  00007FFCA8409FFF  000fa000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * MSASN1                         00007FFCA8260000  00007FFCA8271FFF  00012000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * ADVAPI32                       00007FFCA9EF0000  00007FFCA9F96FFF  000a7000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * msvcrt                         00007FFCA9CD0000  00007FFCA9D6DFFF  0009e000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sechost                        00007FFCABF90000  00007FFCAC02EFFF  0009f000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * RPCRT4                         00007FFCAC120000  00007FFCAC23CFFF  0011d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * ole32                          00007FFCA99F0000  00007FFCA9B45FFF  00156000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * combase                        00007FFCA94B0000  00007FFCA97DCFFF  0032d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * bcryptPrimitives               00007FFCA8BF0000  00007FFCA8C71FFF  00082000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * GDI32                          00007FFCAC030000  00007FFCAC058FFF  00029000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * gdi32full                      00007FFCA8500000  00007FFCA869BFFF  0019c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * msvcp_win                      00007FFCA8460000  00007FFCA84FFFFF  000a0000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * USER32                         00007FFCAB7B0000  00007FFCAB946FFF  00197000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * win32u                         00007FFCA8C80000  00007FFCA8C9FFFF  00020000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * NETAPI32                       00007FFC9FCD0000  00007FFC9FCE8FFF  00019000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * pdh                            00007FFCA48C0000  00007FFCA490CFFF  0004d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * SQLOS                          00007FFC9C2B0000  00007FFC9C2B7FFF  00008000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sqlmin                         00007FFC98220000  00007FFC9B1ECFFF  02fcd000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * WS2_32                         00007FFCAB740000  00007FFCAB7ACFFF  0006d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * OLEAUT32                       00007FFCA9C00000  00007FFCA9CC3FFF  000c4000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sqlTsEs                        00007FFC952B0000  00007FFC95B79FFF  008ca000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sqldk                          00007FFC94D80000  00007FFC952A7FFF  00528000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * opends60                       00007FFC94D70000  00007FFC94D78FFF  00009000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * qds                            00007FFC94C40000  00007FFC94D67FFF  00128000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * svl                            00007FFC94C10000  00007FFC94C3CFFF  0002d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * MSVCP140                       00007FFCA03C0000  00007FFCA0450FFF  00091000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * MPR                            00007FFCA0690000  00007FFCA06AAFFF  0001b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * VCRUNTIME140                   00007FFCA0310000  00007FFCA0328FFF  00019000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * Secur32                        00007FFCA24D0000  00007FFCA24DBFFF  0000c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * WINHTTP                        00007FFCA4740000  00007FFCA4830FFF  000f1000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.24 spid183     * sqllang                        00007FFC95B80000  00007FFC98177FFF  025f8000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * secforwarder                   00007FFC94BF0000  00007FFC94C00FFF  00011000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * bcrypt                         00007FFCA8CA0000  00007FFCA8CC5FFF  00026000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ODBC32                         00007FFC94B30000  00007FFC94BE4FFF  000b5000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * WINTRUST                       00007FFCA8CD0000  00007FFCA8D30FFF  00061000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * WINMM                          00007FFCA0390000  00007FFCA03B3FFF  00024000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * VCRUNTIME140_1                 00007FFCA0B90000  00007FFCA0B9BFFF  0000c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ncrypt                         00007FFCA7D00000  00007FFCA7D25FFF  00026000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * USERENV                        00007FFCA8140000  00007FFCA8168FFF  00029000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * profapi                        00007FFCA8280000  00007FFCA82A3FFF  00024000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * WININET                        00007FFC93C00000  00007FFC940E0FFF  004e1000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * XmlLite                        00007FFCA1E80000  00007FFCA1EB9FFF  0003a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * AUTHZ                          00007FFCA7310000  00007FFCA735BFFF  0004c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * WINMMBASE                      00007FFCA0330000  00007FFCA035CFFF  0002d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * cfgmgr32                       00007FFCA8410000  00007FFCA8459FFF  0004a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * dhcpcsvc                       00007FFCA4AF0000  00007FFCA4B0BFFF  0001c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * NSI                            00007FFCAA230000  00007FFCAA237FFF  00008000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * NETUTILS                       00007FFCA7780000  00007FFCA778DFFF  0000e000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * NTASN1                         00007FFCA7CC0000  00007FFCA7CFBFFF  0003c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SSPICLI                        00007FFCA8170000  00007FFCA819EFFF  0002f000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * DPAPI                          00007FFCA8030000  00007FFCA8039FFF  0000a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * LOGONCLI                       00007FFCA7860000  00007FFCA78A1FFF  00042000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SAMCLI                         00007FFCA4D60000  00007FFCA4D77FFF  00018000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * psapi                          00007FFCA9D70000  00007FFCA9D77FFF  00008000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * kernel.appcore                 00007FFCA8240000  00007FFCA8250FFF  00011000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * instapi150                     00007FFC926E0000  00007FFC926F2FFF  00013000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * CRYPTSP                        00007FFCA8D40000  00007FFCA8D56FFF  00017000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * rsaenh                         00007FFCA75B0000  00007FFCA75E2FFF  00033000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * CRYPTBASE                      00007FFCA7C00000  00007FFCA7C0BFFF  0000c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * imagehlp                       00007FFCABA10000  00007FFCABA2CFFF  0001d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * gpapi                          00007FFCA6E80000  00007FFCA6EA1FFF  00022000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * wkscli                         00007FFCA37E0000  00007FFCA37F7FFF  00018000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * cscapi                         00007FFC91F70000  00007FFC91F81FFF  00012000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * sqlevn70                       000001D105470000  000001D1057A9FFF  0033a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * CLUSAPI                        00007FFC9DFD0000  00007FFC9E0D9FFF  0010a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * DNSAPI                         00007FFCA7790000  00007FFCA7855FFF  000c6000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * IPHLPAPI                       00007FFCA7740000  00007FFCA777DFFF  0003e000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * RESUTILS                       00007FFC9E0E0000  00007FFC9E17DFFF  0009e000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * VERSION                        00007FFCA24F0000  00007FFCA24F9FFF  0000a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * hkruntime                      00007FFC89B70000  00007FFC89E42FFF  002d3000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * dbghelp                        00007FFCA35B0000  00007FFCA379CFFF  001ed000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * hkcompile                      00007FFC89980000  00007FFC89ABFFFF  00140000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * hkengine                       00007FFC89280000  00007FFC89975FFF  006f6000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SHLWAPI                        00007FFCAC0C0000  00007FFCAC111FFF  00052000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ncryptprov                     00007FFCA0AE0000  00007FFCA0B39FFF  0005a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * msv1_0                         00007FFCA79B0000  00007FFCA7A26FFF  00077000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * NtlmShared                     00007FFCA79A0000  00007FFCA79ACFFF  0000d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * cryptdll                       00007FFCA7AA0000  00007FFCA7AB4FFF  00015000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * kerberos                       00007FFCA7AF0000  00007FFCA7BF3FFF  00104000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * schannel                       00007FFCA74E0000  00007FFCA7563FFF  00084000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SECURITY                       000001D78EFE0000  000001D78EFE2FFF  00003000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSCOREE                        00007FFC9B6B0000  00007FFC9B713FFF  00064000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * mscoreei                       00007FFC98180000  00007FFC9821BFFF  0009c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SqlServerSpatial150            00007FFC8ACF0000  00007FFC8AD91FFF  000a2000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * clbcatq                        00007FFCA9B50000  00007FFCA9BF1FFF  000a2000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * msxml3                         00007FFC8AAB0000  00007FFC8ACEAFFF  0023b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ualapi                         00007FFCA0FA0000  00007FFCA0FB9FFF  0001a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SHELL32                        00007FFCAA240000  00007FFCAB738FFF  014f9000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * shcore                         00007FFCA97E0000  00007FFCA9887FFF  000a8000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ESENT                          00007FFCA0C70000  00007FFCA0F92FFF  00323000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ntmarta                        00007FFCA71F0000  00007FFCA7220FFF  00031000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * windows.storage                00007FFCA8D60000  00007FFCA94A7FFF  00748000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * powrprof                       00007FFCA82B0000  00007FFCA830CFFF  0005d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * msoledbsql                     00007FFC8A7E0000  00007FFC8AA54FFF  00275000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * COMDLG32                       00007FFCA9890000  00007FFCA99B6FFF  00127000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * COMCTL32                       00007FFC8A730000  00007FFC8A7D8FFF  000a9000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSOLEDBSQLR                    000001D791460000  000001D791481FFF  00022000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * dhcpcsvc6                      00007FFCA4B90000  00007FFCA4BA5FFF  00016000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * sqlncli11                      00007FFC8A3D0000  00007FFC8A722FFF  00353000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSVCR100                       0000000074D40000  0000000074E11FFF  000d2000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SQLNCLIR11                     000001D7914C0000  000001D7914F7FFF  00038000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * netbios                        00007FFC8D7F0000  00007FFC8D7FBFFF  0000c000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * sqlnclirda11                   00000000749E0000  0000000074D38FFF  00359000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SQLNCLIRDAR11                  000001D791510000  000001D791547FFF  00038000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * clr                            00007FFC940F0000  00007FFC94B2AFFF  00a3b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSVCR120_CLR0400               00007FFC93B00000  00007FFC93BF6FFF  000f7000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * clrjit                         00007FFC9B370000  00007FFC9B49AFFF  0012b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * BatchParser                    00007FFC8A3A0000  00007FFC8A3C9FFF  0002a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SqlAccess                      00007FFC8A320000  00007FFC8A395FFF  00076000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SRVCLI                         00007FFC9FCF0000  00007FFC9FD15FFF  00026000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ftimport                       0000000060000000  0000000060024FFF  00025000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSFTE                          0000000049980000  0000000049D2DFFF  003ae000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * mskeyprotect                   00007FFC9B4A0000  00007FFC9B4B4FFF  00015000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * mswsock                        00007FFCA7A30000  00007FFCA7A96FFF  00067000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ntdsapi                        00007FFCA1550000  00007FFCA1577FFF  00028000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * DSPARSE                        00007FFCA24C0000  00007FFCA24CCFFF  0000d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * rasadhlp                       00007FFCA2BF0000  00007FFCA2BF9FFF  0000a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * fwpuclnt                       00007FFCA4B10000  00007FFCA4B88FFF  00079000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ncryptsslp                     00007FFC9B580000  00007FFC9B5A3FFF  00024000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * xpsqlbot                       00007FFC89FA0000  00007FFC89FA9FFF  0000a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * xpstar                         00007FFC89F20000  00007FFC89F91FFF  00072000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SQLSCM                         00007FFC8A2C0000  00007FFC8A2D3FFF  00014000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * xpstar                         000001D79C2D0000  000001D79C2DCFFF  0000d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * SAMLIB                         00007FFC9FF10000  00007FFC9FF34FFF  00025000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * Sort00060101                   00007FFCA2630000  00007FFCA2642FFF  00013000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * System.Data                    00007FFC88BA0000  00007FFC88F07FFF  00368000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * System.Transactions            00007FFC88B50000  00007FFC88B9EFFF  0004f000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * xplog70                        00007FFCA4180000  00007FFCA4195FFF  00016000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * xplog70                        000001D79D0A0000  000001D79D0A3FFF  00004000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * oledb32                        00007FFC8AED0000  00007FFC8AFBCFFF  000ed000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSDART                         00007FFCA26B0000  00007FFCA26D6FFF  00027000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * Comctl32                       00007FFC85500000  00007FFC85778FFF  00279000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * comsvcs                        00007FFC937D0000  00007FFC93976FFF  001a7000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ACEOLEDB                       00007FFC86DB0000  00007FFC86E30FFF  00081000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSVCR90                        0000000074930000  00000000749D2FFF  000a3000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * mso                            00007FFC784A0000  00007FFC79BDCFFF  0173d000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * msi                            00007FFC78010000  00007FFC78491FFF  00482000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * srpapi                         00007FFCA2220000  00007FFCA2249FFF  0002a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ACECORE                        00007FFC83960000  00007FFC83C54FFF  002f5000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSVCP90                        0000000074850000  0000000074922FFF  000d3000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ACEWSTR                        00007FFC86CD0000  00007FFC86DA4FFF  000d5000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSORES                         000001D79F2F0000  000001D7A381AFFF  0452b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * MSOINTL                        000001DC12AC0000  000001DC12D29FFF  0026a000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ACEINTL                        00007FFCA21E0000  00007FFCA2212FFF  00033000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * msxml6                         00007FFC861C0000  00007FFC86416FFF  00257000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * odbccp32                       00007FFC8A080000  00007FFC8A0A5FFF  00026000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * sqlvdi                         00007FFCA23C0000  00007FFCA23FAFFF  0003b000
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P1Home: 000001EA00000000:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P2Home: 00007FFC95D66469:  059647840F58F883  40245C8B48C03200  C483484824748B48  9090909090C35F30  4C90909090909090  415541544157DC8B  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P3Home: 000001EAC1888230:  00007FFC975C9F10  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001EAC1888280  000001EAC1888290  0024000600000000  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P4Home: 0000002C825F0930:  000000000000002C  0000000000000000  FFFFFFF76430E090  000001EAC1889FD0  0000000000000000  000001EAC1889CE0  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P5Home: FFFFFFFFFFFFFF00:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     P6Home: 000001E225BB5D00:  0000000000000000  FFFFFFFF00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * ContextFlags: 000000000010005F:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA8:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegCs: 0000000000000033:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegDs: 000000000000002B:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegEs: 000000000000002B:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegFs: 0000000000000053:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegGs: 000000000000002B:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *      SegSs: 000000000000002B:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *     EFlags: 0000000000010206:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rax: 000001EAC1889FFC:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rcx: 0000000000000072:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rdx: 0000000000000072:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rbx: 000001EAC1888230:  00007FFC975C9F10  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001EAC1888280  000001EAC1888290  0024000600000000  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rsp: 0000002C825F15D0:  000001EAC1888230  0000002C825F16D0  000001EAC1889FD0  0000000000000000  000001E5DDB48206  000001EA58FA7850  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rbp: 0000002C825F16D0:  00007FFC97573E08  0000E70000000004  000001DBE1359150  0000000700000010  000001000000000A  0000000000000000  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rsi: 000001EAC1889FD0:  002E006F00620064  0055005F006E0066  007800610054004B  0074006C0075004D  0069006C00700069  006000C400720065  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rdi: 000000000000002C:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *         R8: 0000000000000000:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *         R9: FFFFFFF76430E090:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R10: 000001EAC1889FD0:  002E006F00620064  0055005F006E0066  007800610054004B  0074006C0075004D  0069006C00700069  006000C400720065  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R11: 0000000000000000:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R12: 000001EAC1889CE0:  00007FFC975C9BA0  BFF0000000000001  000001EAC1889C40  0000000000000001  000001EAC1889D08  000001EAC1889B80  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R13: 000001EA58FA7850:  00007FFC974A1098  0000009100000001  000001DBE1340060  00000000000002D5  000001EA58FA7BB0  000001DBE1340060  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R14: 000001EAC18882C0:  00007FFC97549C98  0000000000000001  000001DBE1340060  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        R15: 0000000000000018:  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     *        Rip: 00007FFC96483D83:  F575007E3C834266  44C03305EBFF0345  0004C8858B48F88B  7889441070894800  000000031C40C718  E8000004B08D8D48  
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * *******************************************************************************
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-05-26 06:30:01.25 spid183     * Short Stack Dump
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC96483D83 Module(sqllang+0000000000903D83)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC96483310 Module(sqllang+0000000000903310)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D6BF6D Module(sqllang+00000000001EBF6D)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D8C514 Module(sqllang+000000000020C514)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D8C32B Module(sqllang+000000000020C32B)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95DA36A2 Module(sqllang+00000000002236A2)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D8C32B Module(sqllang+000000000020C32B)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D6C1DD Module(sqllang+00000000001EC1DD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D29ADD Module(sqllang+00000000001A9ADD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D6BC75 Module(sqllang+00000000001EBC75)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D6C1DD Module(sqllang+00000000001EC1DD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D29ADD Module(sqllang+00000000001A9ADD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D6A9AF Module(sqllang+00000000001EA9AF)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D29ADD Module(sqllang+00000000001A9ADD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95E09598 Module(sqllang+0000000000289598)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D29ADD Module(sqllang+00000000001A9ADD)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC96490A9B Module(sqllang+0000000000910A9B)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC96490945 Module(sqllang+0000000000910945)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC964907ED Module(sqllang+00000000009107ED)
2022-05-26 06:30:01.27 spid183     00007FFC95D29BB0 Module(sqllang+00000000001A9BB0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you open case with MS. Before opening the case please make sure you are on latest SQL Server 2019 CU. This may be a bug fixed in CU release. - [Shanky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/42379/shanky)

And in response from the OP:

My SQL Server Product version: 15.0.4223.1, file version: 2019.150.4223.1

The SQL Server 2019 Cumulative Update 16 shows the following items that could be related to my error:

1. [14506574](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5011644-cumulative-update-16-for-sql-server-2019-74377be1-4340-4445-93a7-ff843d346896#bkmk_14506574) - An access violation dump occurs when the query runs for a long time in parallel and tries to determine the version of the rowgroup for the particular transactions to read.
2. [14555263](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5011644-cumulative-update-16-for-sql-server-2019-74377be1-4340-4445-93a7-ff843d346896#bkmk_14555263) - An access violation occurs if a query on sys.database_scoped_configurations is waiting for a shared lock on the database while another thread holds the exclusive lock to drop the same database.